# SQL: command to get whether a value exists in multiple columns

Tags: sql, teradata

Normally in Teradata SQL, when we want to check if a column contains one of the possibles values, we do `col1 IN ('val1', 'val2')`, but what if we want to do it the other way i.e. whether a value is in present in one of the few columns `'val1' IN (col1, col2)`.

I want to do it in this manner cause sometimes `col1` or `col2` might store the value that I am interested in. Right now I have been using multiple `LIKE` statements, but it's tedious and prone to error when the number of columns increases.

Comment: `val1 IN (col1, col2)` is valid. don't use quotes around column names

Comment: I tried 'val1' IN (col1, col2) but I get the `[error 42000][3706] [Teradata Database] [TeraJDBC 16.20.00.06] [Error 3706] [SQLState 42000] Syntax error: expected something between the word 'col1' and ','.`

Comment: This is a dumb restriction in Teradata, you can't use columns (or calculations) in an `IN` list. You must rewrite it as a series of `OR`ed conditions (the optimizer would do that anyway). But there's no need for `LIKE` instead of `=` (and LIKE has different comparison rules)